# Onload not working on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, onload

As I'm moving forward with my program I run into trouble using window. or document.onload() to call javascript. This works fine on chrome and firefox, but IE is not using it at all. The current code:

HTML:

```
<body onload = "getEvents()"></body>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        document.ready(function(){ getEvents(); });

        function getEvents(addEvents(variable)){ /*show something*/ };

        function addEvents(variable = ""){}
</script>
```

I tried using document.ready() as suggested by a post on a simular question, but to no result. Leaving it out changes nothing. I don't get why this is not working as the documentation for onload I found suggests it should be supported by IE. So in theorie this should not be an issue at all.

After a usefull comment I decided to call the getEvents function another way to check if this did give an error.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="javascript:getEvents()"/>
```

As I can call this any time I want I got an error when triggering it:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'getEvents' is undefined
```

I understand what this error means and am currently looking for a fix. If anybody knows one I would appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: What is the error in the console?

Comment: I honestly don't know. My output gives no return and I can't seem to find a seperate console bar. No idea if it helps but I'm using netbeans.

Comment: You do not know about the web developer console in the browser?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I did not know I could use f12 for this, however I did check it beforehand. This console also results in zero errors.

Comment: so add break points or console.log lines and see if the method is called.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, I found that another method was being called in a way that IE doesn't support. Apperently that made it for some reason return that getEvents() didn't get defined. Either way it is fixed now.

Comment: I tried accepting the answer I specified below, but it says "you can accept your own answer in 19 hours". Still thanks for the headsup @isherwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem and it seems like it was in a differend part of code entirely. The part that created problems seems to have been calling a function defined as:

`function addEvents(events=""){}`

Which should have been:

`function addEvents(events){}`

I have no idea why this made getEvents() undefined, but at least I know to avoid this in the future. Thanks for all the help!